# Is there an advantage to keeping my dojo uniform on?

Tags: pokemon-sword-shield, pokemon-isle-of-armor

I arrived at the dojo on the Isle of Armor and received my dojo uniform and hairstyle. I noticed that one of the options in the side room of the dojo allows me to change my clothes back to my old style or even something different.

Is there any game-mechanical reason that I need to keep my dojo uniform on while I am completing the dojo challenges and/or traveling around? Obviously, having the uniform gives the island's quests a particular flavor, and that's valuable, but I'm asking about mechanics. For example, will the master yell at me if I put my old clothes back on? Are there NPC's that react differently whether I'm wearing my uniform or not?

Comment: As far as I could tell, there was no difference but I also didn't test it enough to qualify my experience as a full answer.